# WPF Merged ResourceDictionary with resource that binds to resource in another Dictionary not working

Tags: wpf, xaml, mergeddictionaries

I have created a simple project that demonstrates the issue I am having where I get the error:
'Provide value on 'System.Windows.Markup.StaticResourceHolder' threw an exception.' Line number '6' and line position '9'.

The project layout is very simple and I have uploaded it to dropbox:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/451b5zkw8oqgcld/StyleTest1.zip?dl=0

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="StyleTest1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Dictionary1.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Dictionary2.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <Style x:Key="ButtonStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource Button.Static.Background}"/>
            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Button x:Name="button" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Style="{DynamicResource ButtonStyle1}">

        </Button>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Dictionary1.xaml

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:po="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/options"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <GradientStopCollection po:Freeze="true" x:Key="ButtonBackgroundStops">
        <GradientStop Color="#2d2d2f"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#2d2d2f" Offset="1"/>
    </GradientStopCollection>

    <LinearGradientBrush
        po:Freeze="true"    
        x:Key="ButtonBackgroundBrush"           
        GradientStops="{StaticResource ButtonBackgroundStops}"  
        StartPoint="0.5,-0.05"  
        EndPoint="0.5,0.66" />

</ResourceDictionary>
```

Dictionary2.xaml

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <LinearGradientBrush 
        x:Key="Button.Static.Background" 
        GradientStops="{Binding Source={StaticResource ButtonBackgroundBrush}, Path=GradientStops}" 
        StartPoint="{Binding Source={StaticResource ButtonBackgroundBrush}, Path=StartPoint}" 
        EndPoint="{Binding Source={StaticResource ButtonBackgroundBrush}, Path=EndPoint}"/>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

And that's it... if I run that program I get the error:
'Provide value on 'System.Windows.Markup.StaticResourceHolder' threw an exception.' Line number '6' and line position '9'.

However, if I alter MainWindow.xaml to the following I no longer get the issue:
Here is the dropbox link for the modified version:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/ceikh5b8cfecdkw/StyleTest2.zip?dl=0

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="StyleTest2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:StyleTest2"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Dictionary1.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Dictionary2.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <LinearGradientBrush 
                x:Key="Button.Static.Background" 
                GradientStops="{Binding Source={StaticResource ButtonBackgroundBrush}, Path=GradientStops}" 
                StartPoint="{Binding Source={StaticResource ButtonBackgroundBrush}, Path=StartPoint}" />
            <Style x:Key="ButtonStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource Button.Static.Background}"/>
            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Button x:Name="button" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Style="{DynamicResource ButtonStyle1}">

        </Button>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Which would suggest it is a problem with the LinearGradientBrush in Dictionary2.xaml binding to the ButtonBackgroundBrush resource that is located in Dictionary1.xaml.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here and what is the correct way to have a resource in one dictionary reference a resource in another dictionary?

Thanks for your time,

codeOwl

Comment: Why wouldn't you just combine both Dictionary1.xaml and Dictionary2.xaml into one in order to fix the issue if this indeed is a root cause of it? Best regards,

Comment: This is just a demo to reproduce the issue.  In reality I am creating an add-on for a program written in WPF and Dictionary1 is actually the current skin for that program.  So to test I have written a WPF application just like the demo one in this post where I merge in their skin dictionary in the same way I merge in Dictionary1 in the demo...   however it is not working... I am getting the same error... hence this post...

Comment: Please narrow down your question to that particular programming issue and remove overly broad descriptive part. Thanks and regards,

Comment: @AlexBell, not sure what you mean mate.  Basically I get the error mentioned in the question when I to define a resource in one resource dictionary that references a resource in a second resource dictionary, and this question is how do I fix this?

Comment: @AlexBell, while I appreciate the advise, I can not do that.  As I said Dictionary1 is a skin file.  Users can make their own skins, and when they do, they won't have my styles in there.  I am creating styles that use some of the styles in the main skin, so I can assign these to my add-on, but also include my design.  This way I can keep the current skins settings for things like text foreground and background colors etc... so my add-on will match the current skin, but my styles also have stuff that is only applicable to my design in it.

Comment: I can't just add my styles to all existing skin files as they won't be supported by the company that makes the program.

Comment: I am trying to understand the way that WPF works with dictionaries.  As far as I have read what I am doing should work as I am loading Dictionary1 before Dictionary2 in the merged resources.

Comment: Move them out of MainWindow.xaml and into App,xaml in <Application.Resources>.  Does that make a difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Use `DynamicResource` in-place of `StaticResource` in Dictionary2,

   or
2. Merge Dictionary 1 in Dictionary2, then there won't be any issues.

Dictionary2 will look like :

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="Dictionary1.xaml"/>
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

    <LinearGradientBrush 
        x:Key="Button.Static.Background" 
        GradientStops="{Binding Source={StaticResource ButtonBackgroundBrush}, Path=GradientStops}" 
        StartPoint="{Binding Source={StaticResource ButtonBackgroundBrush}, Path=StartPoint}" 
        EndPoint="{Binding Source={StaticResource ButtonBackgroundBrush}, Path=EndPoint}"/>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

Comment: thanks for the response.  But as stated in the comments of the question, I can't.  This is just a demo to reproduce the issue. In reality I am creating an add-on for a program written in WPF and Dictionary1 is the equivalent of the current skin for that program. So to test I have written a WPF application just like the demo one in this post where I merge in their skin dictionary in the same way I merge in Dictionary1 in the demo... however it is not working... I am getting the same error... hence this post...

Comment: can u explain using a figure what u r trying to do ?

Comment: I am trying to create an add-on for a program that already has a ResourceDictionary of styles.  I want to extend some of the styles in their ResourceDictionary with my on styles.  I can not add my styles to their resource dictionary as my Add-in compiles into a DLL that is then loaded into their program.  My styles will be compiled into my DLL, I do not have access to their styles, but as they support skinning I know what their styles are.

Comment: So at the end of the day I need to be able to define a style in one ResourceDictionary that references a style in another ResourceDictionary, just like the first demo project in my original post attempts to do.  I can't see a reason, based on everything I have read, why that won't work.

Comment: brilliant.  Thanks for taking the time to work this out mate.  Really appreciate it!!